# rownum vs max in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a couple of queries to get latest modified parent_id

with **max** keyword:

```
select max(parent_id)
from sample_table
where modified_date=(select max(modified_date) 
FROM sample_table
where id = 'test') and id = 'test';
```

with **rownum** keyword:

```
select * 
from (
select parent_id,modified_date
from sample_table
where id = 'test' 
order by modified_date desc) 
WHERE  rownum <= 1 ;
```

Both the queries returning same and correct result.

Which one is better and faster query..

Comment: I'd guess it depnds also on the indices available

Comment: For sure they do not return the same result, `select max(parent_id)` differs to `select * `

Answer (score 1):

Your query is somewhat unpredictable because two records can have the same `modified_date`. So you have to apply a trick to return a single row only.

The first query is deterministic: It takes the latestd `modified_date`; if it returns several rows it takes the one with the highest `parent_id`. The second query is unpredicatable: it depends on how Oracle executes the query.

I would use the second query and modify it slightly to move the two order criteria close to each other:

```
select * 
from (
    select parent_id,modified_date
    from sample_table
    where id = 'test' 
    order by modified_date desc, parent_id desc) 
WHERE  rownum <= 1;
```

This type of query can also be better extended to return more columns, namely by adding it to the inner SELECT clause. In the other query, it's trickier.

Answer (score 1):

You would say the best way is this one:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(parent_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY modified_date desc, parent_id desc),    
    MAX(modified_date)
FROM sample_table
WHERE ID = 'test';
```

Comment: Agreed. In [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) we can read: _When you need a value from the first or last row of a sorted group, but the needed value is not the sort key, the `FIRST` and `LAST` functions eliminate the need for self-joins or views and **enable better performance**._